# "Read Later" for Twitter posts with fewest taps possible

Tags: twitter

Most Twitter apps I've tried require at least three taps to even get to "share", which then makes me select the thing I want (I never share those links on FB or G+, I just want to save them for later, when I have a bigger screen).

What I want is something similar to Tweetbot on iOS: hold the link, tap "Send to Pocket". Is there some technique I'm missing? Is there an app that can let me save with fewer taps?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but [Slices for Twitter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onelouder.tweetvision) will let you tap on a link to open it up in the built-in web browser, then tap on the share button to bring up the list of targets for URLs, including Pocket.

You don't have to wait for the page to finish loading before sharing the link to Pocket, which allows this process to be fairly quick.

That's 3 total taps to save something to Pocket. I admit, a built-in method of saving a tweeted link to Pocket/Instapaper would be much better. Tap & hold on a link to bring up options, then tap on a Read Later link.